# Blazor Can't Update UI

Tags: c#, blazor

I've seen a lot of posts dealing with issues in updating the UI in Blazor, but none of the previous methods I read worked. I am trying to replicate some of the Password Policy Validators I've seen in JavaScript. However, I am trying to do it in C# with Blazor. If I step through the code in Debug Mode it works perfect but going live I can't get the UI to update even with a StateHasChanged Request as seen below:
[image]
Code:

```
private bool pwSpecialChar { get; set; }
private bool pwUpper { get; set; }
private bool pwLower { get; set; }
private bool pwDigit { get; set; }
private bool pwLength { get; set; }

private async Task ValidatePassword(KeyboardEventArgs args)
{
    string pw = args.Key;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Password))
    {
        if (Model.Password.Length < 8) { pwLength = false; } else { pwLength = true; }
        if (Model.Password.Any(c => char.IsSymbol(c)) == false) { pwSpecialChar = false; } else { pwSpecialChar = true; }
        if (Model.Password.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c)) == false) { pwDigit = false; } else { pwDigit = true; }
        if ((Model.Password.Where(char.IsUpper).Count() >= 1) == false) { pwUpper = false; } else { pwUpper = true; }
        if ((Model.Password.Where(char.IsLower).Count() >= 1) == false) { pwLower = false; } else { pwLower = true; }
    }
    else
    {
        pwLower = false;
        pwUpper = false;
        pwDigit = false;
        pwSpecialChar = false;
        pwLength = false;
    }
    await Task.Delay(500);
    await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <h5>You must change your password before you can proceed.</h5>
    <ol>
    @if (pwLength == false)
    {
        <li style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg> &nbsp; Must Be at Least 8 Characters in Length</li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li style="color:green; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-check-circle"><path d="M22 11.08V12a10 10 0 1 1-5.93-9.14"></path><polyline points="22 4 12 14.01 9 11.01"></polyline></svg> &nbsp; Must Be at Least 8 Characters in Length</li>
    }
    @if (pwSpecialChar == false)
    {
        <li style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg> &nbsp; Pasword Must Contain at Least One Special Character</li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li style="color:green; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-check-circle"><path d="M22 11.08V12a10 10 0 1 1-5.93-9.14"></path><polyline points="22 4 12 14.01 9 11.01"></polyline></svg> &nbsp; Pasword Must Contain at Least One Special Character</li>
    }
    @if (pwDigit == false)
    {
        <li style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg> &nbsp; Pasword Must Contain at Least One Number</li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li style="color:green; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-check-circle"><path d="M22 11.08V12a10 10 0 1 1-5.93-9.14"></path><polyline points="22 4 12 14.01 9 11.01"></polyline></svg> &nbsp; Pasword Must Contain at Least One Number</li>
    }
    @if (pwUpper == false)
    {
        <li style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg> &nbsp; Pasword Must Contain at Least One Upper Case Letter</li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li style="color:green; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-check-circle"><path d="M22 11.08V12a10 10 0 1 1-5.93-9.14"></path><polyline points="22 4 12 14.01 9 11.01"></polyline></svg> &nbsp; Pasword Must Contain at Least One Upper Case Letter</li>
    }
    @if (pwLower == false)
    {
        <li style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg> &nbsp; Pasword Must Contain at Least One Lower Case Letter</li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li style="color:green; font-weight:bold;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-check-circle"><path d="M22 11.08V12a10 10 0 1 1-5.93-9.14"></path><polyline points="22 4 12 14.01 9 11.01"></polyline></svg> &nbsp; Pasword Must Contain at Least One Lower Case Letter</li>
    }
    </ol>
    <EditForm Model="Model" OnValidSubmit="ChangePassword" OnInvalidSubmit="ChangePasswordError" id="validateForm">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                     <div>
                        <label>New Password *</label>
                            <SfTextBox @bind-Value="@Model.Password" Placeholder="New Password *" Type="InputType.Password" OnKeyDown="ValidatePassword" required></SfTextBox>
                            <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Password)" />
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <label>Confirm New Password *</label>
                    <SfTextBox @bind-Value="@Model.ConfirmPassword" Placeholder="Confirm New Password *" Type="InputType.Password" required></SfTextBox>
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.ConfirmPassword)" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change Password</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the sequencing of the events.  The key events occur and thus run `ValidatePassword` on every keypress, but `InputText`, and almost certainly `SFTextBox`, only update the model value when the input loses focus.  There's no way to change this behaviour on `InputText`, and probably `SFTextBox`.

The standalone demo page below shows how you can resolve your issue using the `oninput` event on the control and capturing the entered text directly using the `ChangeEventArgs`.

```
@page "/password"
<h3>PasswordTest</h3>

<EditForm EditContext="this.editContext">
    <InputText type="password" @bind-Value="model.Password" @oninput="CheckPassword"></InputText>
</EditForm>
<div>@enteredPassword</div>
<div>@errorMessage</div>
@code {

    private Model model { get; set; } = new Model();

    private string enteredPassword = string.Empty;
    private string errorMessage = "Too short! Keep Typing...";

    private EditContext editContext;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.editContext = new EditContext(model);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void CheckPassword(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        this.enteredPassword = e.Value.ToString();
        if (this.enteredPassword.Length > 7)
            errorMessage = "Good to Go.";
        else
            errorMessage = $"Too short by {this.enteredPassword.Length - 8}! Keep Typing...";
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Spot on. Amazing how difficult this simple task was... Or at least my lack of understanding but you got it just right! I had to reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Componets.ChangeEventArgs explicitly since Syncfusion has a Blazor.Navigations.ChangeEventArgs but not everyone is using Syncfusion controls so in many cases they will not need to do similarly.

Comment: No problem.  I've written custom InputBase controls so have dug deep into the Blazor code base.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <SfTextBox @bind-Value="@Model.Password" 
>     Placeholder="New Password *" 
>     Type="InputType.Password" 
>     OnKeyDown="ValidatePassword" 
>     required></SfTextBox>
> ```

The `OnKeyDown` event might not be firing correctly, try using `@onkeypress` instead.

```
<SfTextBox @bind-Value="@Model.Password" 
         Placeholder="New Password *" 
         Type="InputType.Password" 
         @onkeypress="ValidatePassword" 
         required></SfTextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply gave this a try as well and in combination with the first reply as they had suggested, but for some reason I can't get this to update?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the you are not properly awaiting the ValidatePassword function. (Not sure, only what I think is happening). When calling a Task specifically you need to await it. Like this:

```
OnKeyDown="@( async (e) => await ValidatePassword(e))"
```

Then there are also calling the `StateHasChanged()` function in another thread, two removed from the original that is not being awaited. Here is how I handle async functions that requires an await:

UI:

```
<Button @onclick="ValidatePassword" />
<input type="submit" @onclick="ValidatePassword" />
```

Code:

```
async void ValidatePassword()
{
   ...
   await Task.Delay(500);
   StateHasChanged();
}
```

In this case it's a `void` and not a `Task` so the UI will wait for it, but since it is an `async void` you can still await it and I believe it will execute in the same thread. As a result you can just call `StateHasChanged()` as an synchronous function.

---

Also as @DekuDeku has mentioned you might just need to use `@onkeypress` instead if you are really concerned about which button has been pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you said makes sense and I thought for sure this would be the fix... but trying both methods amazingly neither of them set it off.